# What should I read about C++ to create custom Firewall for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm just a web developer and I don't know C++ at all. But I need to create custom Firewall for Windows and I would like to learn how to do it by myself.

Could you just post me the links to the pages on the Internet where I can read respective information on C++ to get started?

Unlike built-in Windows Firewall, my custom Firewall must allows specific whitelisted websites not by their IP addresses, but instead specific urls including wildcards like `example.com/*`

And like Windows Firewall, only user with admin prevs should be able to change settings, turn of the Firewall or uninstall it. At the same time, the Firewall must run only for standard user.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [Windows Filtering Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page) you need. If this isn't enough for you, then you have to build your own kernel driver (example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/windows-filtering-platform-sample/)).

The topic is too complex and way beyond any "web developer" - you need to be a hardcore OS developer to mess with stuff like that.

Start by reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and then you 'd need some 5+ years of Win32 API studying, for the *basics*.